# Dealing with Euler's function

Tags: number-theory

How could I go about proving that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$a\ ≡ b\mod n$$ iff $e(a/n) = e(b/n)$ where

$$e(a) = e^{2i\pi a}$$

Using Euler's formula which states that $e^{ia} = \cos a + i\ \sin a$

I tried writing this as $e(a) = e^{{2i\pi a}/n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\cos(2 \pi x)=\cos(2 \pi y)$ and $\sin(2\pi x)= \sin (2 \pi y)$ if and only if $x-y \in \mathbb Z$.